# Presentation software requires admin rights to install - any way to remove this requirement?

Tags: wireless-networking, video, hdmi, administrator, vga

I have some wireless presentation software which I use in a meeting room in order to allow end users to hold presentations here and wirelessly have their laptop screens showing on the TV on the wall.

Unfortunately the .exe file requires admin rights to install therefore requiring that either the user requests temporary admin rights beforehand, I install it using my admin account or that we use a VGA/HDMI cable.

Is there a way to remove the admin right requirement from a .exe or a .msi file so that it can be installed freely by any user?

We are using XP for now but will be moving to 7 soon.

Thanks

James

Comment: Sounds like the reason it requires admin rights to install is because of a domain policy.

Answer (score 0):

You could try extracting the contents of the installer using [Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract/) or similar software to see if you can run the program without installing it.

If the software controls any hardware or has to modify system files you probably will be out of luck, you generally need admin privileges for these tasks.